# Codeigniter Limit Start

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i got a problem with a query with CodeIgniter 3.

I'm trying to get all users from database with limit and start excluding the ID of the user who is getting the list.

That's my model:

```
public function getUserList($id,$limit,$start){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('register');
    $this->db->where('register.id' != $id);
    $this->db->order_by("id"); 
    $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

And that's the controller:

```
public function users(){
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
    $start = $_GET['start'];

    $data = $this->User_model->getUserList($id,$limit,$start);

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
    $this->load->view('api', $data);
}
```

The problem is this function return me an empty array instead an array of 5 array.

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: is returning an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Custom key/value method:
>
> You can include an operator in the first parameter in order to control the comparison:

Change below line.

```
 $this->db->where('register.id !=', $id);
```